Where I can see the creation date of my project in firebase?
Where I can see the creation date of my project in firebase? I have a project in firebase. I want to see when I have created it. In console, there are project id, name and web api key, not creation date. Unable to find any option.

Not sure why you need it and I can't seem to find that info on the UI as well but if you turn on the browser's DevTools and track the network, you will find some GetProject requests with apparently the creation time info:

That number apparently is the Unix second timestamp of the creation time. You can put it into the Javascript console right in that DevTool window, for example:


console.log(new Date(1719415523 * 1000))



This gives me the creation time at "2024-06-26T15:25:23.000Z", which I guess is correct.
